# Is there a way to scope `require`s and `import`s to the inside of a function?

Tags: function, clojure, dependencies

I'm a little confused about the scope of `require`s and `import`s in Clojure.  Can I somehow require dependencies that only stay in scope within a function?

When I do something like the following, I get the shown error.

```
user=> (defn test1 [x] (require '[taoensso.timbre :as timbre]) (timbre/log x))

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: timbre, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1203922056301029971.clj:1:57)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't disagree with Grav's suggestion--that is an option--but I don't see much of a drawback to loading a dependency for use only with one function.

Occasionally there is a reason to temporarily switch namespaces within a file using either `ns` or `in-ns`:

```
(ns foo.bar)

... more code here ...

(ns foo.parameters [:require foo.baz :as bz])
(def my-parm (bz/inc2 42))
(ns foo.bar)
```

You could use this to make a `require`d namespace available only temporarily, but this is something that usually should be avoided.

Like many people, [Colin Jones' blog post](https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html) is my favorite introduction to namespaces.

Comment: Everyone's warning me that this is something to avoid doing.  Now, obviously, that's true for your everyday Clojure code.  Just for posterity, I want to acknowledge that I wouldn't do this unless it was for some kind of special case black magic.

Comment: In that case it would be OK. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of your motivation for moving the `require` statements out of the `ns` declarations. The `require` statements state the dependencies of that namespace.

If these dependencies only relate to certain functions of the namespace, you might consider moving those functions into a different namespace, thereby freeing the first namespace of dependencies, and creating looser coupling.

Answer (score 2):

No, these are only designed to be used in your `ns` form.

Comment: I think you meant to say that `:require` can only be used in the `ns` form.  `require` can be used outside of `ns`, although this is of course uncommon, except at a repl prompt.

Comment: What you say is true, but it's not what I meant to say. The point of this question is how to require things "scoped" to a particular function, and the important thing for an answer to say is "no, you cannot do this, here is what you should do instead'. The fact that you can call `require` from the repl is not really relevant and would just confuse the issue for someone asking this question.